# Escaping a comma

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, url-validation

I have this regex

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

but I'm having trouble with the comma. Escaping the comma like this `\,` does not solve the problem. What can I do to make this regex works work??

My code:

```
if (preg_match("/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/", "https://google.com/picture.jpeg")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should at least explain what you want to do with your regex, maybe your regex itself is wrong. You might also want to give us example strings of what should work and what shouldn't. escaping you 3 `/`'s made it work for me : https://regex101.com/r/yQ1oG8/1

Comment: I see the problem is with running the regex. There are 2 issues: 1) the code does not compile, or 2) after escaping the double quotation mark, no match is returned, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single apostrophes here and escape the single apostrophe:

```
if (preg_match('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', "https://google.com/picture.jpeg")) {
//             ^                                                                                                                                                                        ^                 ^
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/x8UoD7)

Otherwise, you would have to double the backslashes to actually represent literal backslashes. Note that escaping a comma is not necessary at all. You don't even have to escape the hyphen at the final position inside the character class `[a-z0-9.-]`.

Comment: I have just added arrows to show where I made the changes. Please let me know if there is anything else you'd like to enhance here.

Answer (score 1):

You've unescaped delimiter over here i.e two after `https?://` needs to be `https?:\/\/` and one over here `[a-z]{2,4}/` needs to be `[a-z]{2,4}\/`

```
(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```